I have round trip overseas. Can I go to a different country and return back?
I booked my flight tickets round-trip 4 months ago, USA to Malaysia for a 2-week vacation. I have a friend's wedding in South Korea, late notice from my friend for the invitation.
I was wondering if I can book a flight round-trip 3 days to South Korea back to Malaysia during my 2-week vacation?

Why do you think you can’t?

What's your nationality and status first?

IME, using a return ticket to a country in which you do not  have resident status can raise questions, however you have the return half of your Malaysia ticket in hand in case that comes up.
